# Add parameter to python decorator of a class

Tags: python

How can I pass the parameter `name` to the dispatch decorator?

```
import functools

class Dispatcher:
    def dispatch(self, func): # passing name here not worked
        @functools.wraps(func) # passing name here not worked
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
          print('the NAME paramater is:', ???)
        return wrapper


@dispatcher.dispatch(name='foobar')
def send(param):
    pass

send(param='parameter 1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn the `dispatch` method into a method that returns a decorator. This allows you to call it when decorating the function with an argument.

```py
import functools


class Dispatcher:

    def dispatch(self, name):
        def decorator(func):
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                print('Calling decorated function', name)
                func(*args, **kwargs)
                print('Decorated function completed', name)
            return wrapper

        return decorator


dispatcher = Dispatcher()
@dispatcher.dispatch(name='foobar')
def send(param):
    print('Sending with param', param)


send(param='parameter 1')
```

**Output**

```
Calling decorated function foobar
Sending with param parameter 1
Decorated function completed foobar
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to use `functools.wraps()` decorator on your `wrapper()` to avoid metadata loss. Also it's much better to define `dispatch` as static method using decorator `staticmethod`.

Comment: How can I use your solution with `functools.wraps`?

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the answer to show use with `functools.wraps`. It is not necessarily better to define it as a `staticmethod` - it depends entirely on the purpose of the decorator and whether the `Dispatcher` instance attributes are used in the computation. I assume they are, otherwise it probably makes more sense not to use a class here at all.

Comment: @DHudson, your decorator losing return value. And **it is necessary** to define it like static method, otherwise it violates logic of decorators.

Comment: You can `return func(*args, **kwargs)` if you like to retain the value. It depends on the purpose of the decorator which is unspecified in the question. The question doesn't even show the original function being called, so they could be using it for anything. As the question defines the decorator within a class, it's reasonable to assume that they wish to use an instance's attributes in the decorator or wrapped function, a `staticmethod` would prevent this. @Skhaz, if you are not using any attributes of the `Dispatcher` class, you would probably be better off just using a function.

Comment: Correct. I am not using the func at all, it's just to catch all parameters passed to it.

Comment: @DHudson, you **can not**  use `return` because it will exit from function and skip further `print`. If code in question contains mistakes it's not an obligatory to keep them in answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code plus you didn't specify exactly what you wanted but I however came up with something that seems like a solution to your problem!

```
import functools
class Dispatcher:

    def dispatch(self, func): # passing name here not worked
        @functools.wraps(func) # passing name here not worked
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
          print('the name paramater is:', kwargs['param'])
        return wrapper

dispatcher = Dispatcher()

@dispatcher.dispatch
def send(param):
    pass

send(param='parameter 1')
```

I created an instance of the Dispatcher class to avoid the error saying required argument self is missing. Secondly I didn't called the dispatch method so that it can take 'send' as func. That's how decorators work.

You sent in a keyword argument to 'send', so I accessed it using kwargs['param'].

I hope I've helped a brother!

Comment: I want the parameter `name` from `@dispatcher.dispatch(name='some name')`